# File exists through Dir() validation, yet it doesn't get attached on mailing macro

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, mailing

I have a macro that can send multiple mails with attachments to an specific user, this had no problem when I sent 1 file to 1 user, but I modified it so it loops to send one mail with many attachments (so it doesn't fills the recipients inbox). The problem now is that it's not attaching any file at all.

First I ask the user to specify the folder where the files are stored so I get the `cadenaDirectorio` (path) then it iterates through the users emails to get the address, then I search for each file hasn't been sent yet and finally validate with `Dir()` function if the file exists or not, which correctly returns true or false but it doesn't attach anything never.

```
For Each llave In dictMov.Keys

    Set objMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'MAIL OBJECT
    
    
    'GET EMAIL
    For filaIndiceFuenteM = 2 To filaFuenteUltimaM
        If llave = planillaFuenteM.Cells(filaIndiceFuenteM, "K") Then
            mailJefe = planillaFuenteM.Cells(filaIndiceFuenteM, "M")
        End If
    Next filaIndiceFuenteM
    
    For filaIndiceFuente = 437 To filaFuenteUltima
        
        Set objMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'MAIL CREATION
        
        'GET MAIL
        For filaIndiceFuenteM = 2 To filaFuenteUltimaM
            If llave = planillaFuenteM.Cells(filaIndiceFuenteM, "K") Then
                mailJefe = planillaFuenteM.Cells(filaIndiceFuenteM, "M")
            End If
        Next filaIndiceFuenteM

        'GET DOCS TO SEND
            
            If llave = planillaFuente.Cells(filaIndiceFuente, "L") And planillaFuente.Cells(filaIndiceFuente, "AA") = "SIN DESP" Then
                'LOOK FOR THE FILES
                archivoFuente = Dir
                cadenaFuente = ""
                
                archivoFuente = Dir(cadenaDirectorio & planillaFuente.Cells(filaIndiceFuente, "C") & "*.pdf")
                cadenaFuente = cadenaDirectorio & archivoFuente
                If Dir(archivoFuente) = "" Then

                    noExistentes = noExistentes & vbNewLine & planillaFuente.Cells(filaIndiceFuente, "D")
                    
                Else
                   
                    objMail.Attachments.Add archivoFuente

                End If
            End If
    Next filaIndiceFuente
    
    If noExistentes <> "" Then MsgBox noExistentes
    
    objMail.To = mailJefe 'TO
    objMail.Subject = "Contrato de Trabajo" 'SUBJECT
    objMail.Body = "THIS IS A TEST MAIL" 'MAIL BODY
    
    objMail.Display
    
    mailJefe = ""
    pendientesDoc = ""
    noExistentes = ""
    
    
Next llave
```

Comment: I think you did a typo, your if statment seems false : `If Dir(archivoFuente) = "" Then` should be `If Dir(archivoFuente)  <> "" Then`

Comment: @Dorian Hey pal, I switched the condition and moved what was inside the ´if´ to the ´else´ but I still get no attachments on the mail screen...

Comment: Please edit your code so I can see what you got now

Comment: @Dorian Done! The file name is 1:1 against the code but I don't see what I'm missing :(

Comment: Please tell me if my answer helped you to fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try :

```
For Each llave In dictMov.Keys

    Set objMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'MAIL OBJECT


    'GET EMAIL
    For filaIndiceFuenteM = 2 To filaFuenteUltimaM
        If llave = planillaFuenteM.Cells(filaIndiceFuenteM, "K") Then
            mailJefe = planillaFuenteM.Cells(filaIndiceFuenteM, "M")
        End If
    Next filaIndiceFuenteM

    For filaIndiceFuente = 437 To filaFuenteUltima

        Set objMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'MAIL CREATION

        'GET MAIL
        For filaIndiceFuenteM = 2 To filaFuenteUltimaM
            If llave = planillaFuenteM.Cells(filaIndiceFuenteM, "K") Then
                mailJefe = planillaFuenteM.Cells(filaIndiceFuenteM, "M")
            End If
        Next filaIndiceFuenteM

        'GET DOCS TO SEND

            If llave = planillaFuente.Cells(filaIndiceFuente, "L") And planillaFuente.Cells(filaIndiceFuente, "AA") = "SIN DESP" Then
                'LOOK FOR THE FILES
                archivoFuente = Dir
                cadenaFuente = ""

                archivoFuente = Dir(cadenaDirectorio & planillaFuente.Cells(filaIndiceFuente, "C") & "*.pdf")
                cadenaFuente = cadenaDirectorio & archivoFuente
                If Dir(archivoFuente) <> "" Then
                    'IF TRUE (EXISTS) THEN ATTACH

                    objMail.Attachments.Add cadenaFuente

                Else
                    'IF FILE NEEDS TO BE SENT BUT DOESN'T EXISTS SHOW VARIABLE AS MSGBOX LATER
                    noExistentes = noExistentes & vbNewLine & planillaFuente.Cells(filaIndiceFuente, "D")
                End If
            End If
    Next filaIndiceFuente

    If noExistentes <> "" Then MsgBox noExistentes

    objMail.To = mailJefe 'TO
    objMail.Subject = "Contrato de Trabajo" 'SUBJECT
    objMail.Body = "THIS IS A TEST MAIL" 'MAIL BODY

    objMail.Display

    mailJefe = ""
    pendientesDoc = ""
    noExistentes = ""


Next llave
```

You had to specify the path of your file and not only the name and your if statment was also wrong, I think you did 2 typo =)

Comment: With this it skips the ´objMail.Attachments.Add cadenaFuente´ it has to be equals to ´""´ somehow

Comment: @AbdónAraya but why, thats not logic equal to null means don’t exist ... can you explain me the logic ?

Comment: If dir() = "" then it adds the attachment but if I try dir() <> "" then it skips to the else statement. I know that it shouldn't be null but somehow i'ts working that way :(

Comment: Yeah, I mean it passes as true but the file isn't attached.

Comment: @AbdónAraya can you debug.print cadenaFuente